# convolution Young inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, group-theory, number-theory, inequality

I am considering Young inequality on finite Abelian group,the convolution young inequality is
$\frac{1}{q_1}+\frac{1}{q_2}=1+\frac{1}{r}$,$f_1,f_2$ are functions on group,i want to proof $\left\|f_1*f_2\right\|_r\leq \left\|f_1\right\|_{q_1}\left\|f_2\right\|_{q_2}$,on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the inequality is $\frac{1}{2}((1+k_1k_2)^r+(k_1+k_2)^r)^{\frac{1}{r}}\leq (1+k_1^{q_1})^{\frac{1}{q_1}}(1+k_2^{q_2})^{\frac{1}{q_2}}$.i have search on Google,but paper on Google only have result on Lie group,but i haven't learn lie group.Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Is $p$ equal to $r$ and $q_i$ to $r_i$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg oh，yes..